# (SQL) How do I differentiate 2 columns from different tables with the same name when selecting?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm using an Oracle 12c SQL server. The goal is to create a view containing each company and the drugs it produces.

How can I differentiate two columns with the exact same name but located in different tables using SELECT?
All relevant code below, including results with error.

I understand why I might be getting a duplicate name error as they both have the same header "name", but thought I handled it by identifying the table beforehand (i.e. pc.name and dg.name). Help!

SQL Tables Being Joined:

[image]

SQL Column Naming Error:

[image]

Comment: Rename one of the columns in your select list? The table name qualifier does not change the column name, only resolves ambiguity on where to get that data from

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Why tag sql server when the question is about oracle?

Comment: @ATC: probably because the automatic tagging was triggered by  "Oracle 12 **SQL Server**" and Ryo didn't bother to check if the tags made sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have ambiguous column names in output from your view:

```
pc.name, dg.name
```

Adding alias for columns should solve this:

```
pc.name as pc_name, dg.name as dg_name
```